Log messages from specific user on discord
I'm trying to make a Python program that logs messages from specific users on Discord. The only tutorials I've found about logging all messages, please help.
I wanted to make a message logger that logs messages only from specific users, but I didn't find any helpful tutorials.

Hmm, could you not follow the tutorial on logging everything, and then just limit it to only trigger for a user with a specified ID
